# extracting time from datetime in R

Tags: r, date

I have a column "datetime" which have value as "899-12-30 07:00:00"

on checking the information I am getting.

```
> typeof(time_info$datetime)
[1] "double"
> class(time_info$datetime)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I want to extract just the time which is 0700 without seconds in this case. How can I do this ?

Comment: answer is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756615/remove-seconds-from-time-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this using `format`

```
format(strptime(str1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H%M")
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "899-12-30 07:00:00"
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say we have Time.now ( youhave your own time) that is the way

```
t = Time.now
t.strftime("%I:%M%p")
```

Answer (score -2):

Or you can directly extract time part:

```
substr("899-12-30 07:00:00",11,15)
# [1] "07:00"
```

Comment: This changes the value to a string, losing the ability to perform date-time arithmetic.